# How to concatenate the created resources in a list so I can delete them later in test as part of clean up?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm performing the following code to get the response field from executing a gatling http request and appending it to a list but in response I see the list is mostly showing the same itemId. I wonder if this is because of concurrency ? I am making this list so I can capture the resources after each create operation call and at the end of test, can iterate over this list to perform a clean up/delete of items as in using "after" hook of gatling.

In simulation class:

```
var responseIdList = List[String]() 

val scenario1 = scenario(" TEST ")
        .exec(Create())
        .exec(session => {
            item = session("itemId").as[String].trim
            println("%%%%%%%%%%% item ID =====>>>>>>>>>> " + item)
            responseIdList = item :: responseIdList
            println("%%%%%%%%%%%  List =====>>>>>>>>>> " + responseIdList)
            session}
        )
 setUp(
    scenario1.inject(atOnceUsers(5))
)
```

Gatling action:

```
   def Create():HttpRequestBuilder= {

      http("CREATE API")
       .post(Host + "/items")
       .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token)
       .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
       .body(StringBody(
         """{ "name" : "Item1"
         |}""".stripMargin)).asJson
       .check(status.is(200))
       .check(jsonPath("$.itemId").saveAs("itemId"))

   }
```

Here is the response after executing above code:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%% item ID =====>>>>>>>>>> dc7e4024-c51e-46ce-93be-6ba1dad3679e
    %%%%%%%%%%% item ID =====>>>>>>>>>> 0bf84d48-ccea-4f10-93b3-ea464adcc952
    %%%%%%%%%%% item ID =====>>>>>>>>>> 072361b2-5c49-4641-a27c-c346c01dde99
    %%%%%%%%%%% item ID =====>>>>>>>>>> dc7e4024-c51e-46ce-93be-6ba1dad3679e
    %%%%%%%%%%% List =====>>>>>>>>>> List(0bf84d48-ccea-4f10-93b3-ea464adcc952, 072361b2-5c49-4641-a27c-c346c01dde99)
    %%%%%%%%%%% List =====>>>>>>>>>> List(0bf84d48-ccea-4f10-93b3-ea464adcc952, 0bf84d48-ccea-4f10-93b3-ea464adcc952, 072361b2-5c49-4641-a27c-c346c01dde99)

    %%%%%%%%%%% item ID =====>>>>>>>>>> dc7e4024-c51e-46ce-93be-6ba1dad3679e

    %%%%%%%%%%%  List =====>>>>>>>>>> List(0bf84d48-ccea-4f10-93b3-ea464adcc952, 0bf84d48-ccea-4f10-93b3-ea464adcc952, 0bf84d48-ccea-4f10-93b3-ea464adcc952, 0bf84d48-ccea-4f10-93b3-ea464adcc952, 072361b2-5c49-4641-a27c-c346c01dde99)
```

Even though on simulation of the scenario there were 5 different item Ids being created but somehow list is  showing the same items. Is there a better data structure or option for me to use? Kindly advice as I'm a beginner in both gatling and scala .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a List and var global references is a wrong strategy because it's not threadsafe.

You should use vals and a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue`:

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue

   def Create():HttpRequestBuilder= {

      http("CREATE API")
       .post(Host + "/items")
       .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token)
       .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
       .body(StringBody(
         """{ "name" : "Item1"
         |}""".stripMargin)).asJson
       .check(status.is(200))
       .check(jsonPath("$.itemId").saveAs("itemId"))

   }

// EDIT: global threadsafe structure stored in an immutable reference
val responseIdList = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue[String]() 

val scenario1 = scenario(" TEST ")
        .exec(Create())
        .exec(session => {
            // EDIT: local val here instead of global var
            val item = session("itemId").as[String].trim
            println("%%%%%%%%%%% item ID =====>>>>>>>>>> " + item)
            responseIdList.offer(item)
            // EDIT: print queue content
            println("%%%%%%%%%%%  List =====>>>>>>>>>> " + util.Arrays.toString(responseIdList.toArray))
            session}
        )
 setUp(
    scenario1.inject(atOnceUsers(5))
)
```

Comment: Actually I gave a try using ConcurrentLinkedQueue and I see the same issue , 4/5  elements that got added to list are same . So this didn't help.

Comment: So on digging I found "By default in Scala this list is immutable, so you can be sure that the list cannot be modified by other threads, because it cannot be modified at all." Also another finding is that  using the exact var to add in list won't work ie.; instead of ```responseIdList = item :: responseIdList``` rather do as 
 ```responseIdList =  session("itemId").as[String].trim :: responseIdList```

Comment: "Actually I gave a try using ConcurrentLinkedQueue and I see the same issue , 4/5 elements that got added to list are same . So this didn't help." that's also because you're using a global var reference "item" and this is not threadsafe as well. Editing my answer...

Comment: "Also another finding is that using the exact var to add in list won't work ie" the problem not List itself, it's updating a var which is not atomic, hence not threadsafe.